# Can't connect on port 22 on Xfinity

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I'm trying to upgrade my modem on Xfinity as mine is way past EOL and slow.

I tried two different Arris wireless modem/router combos from Xfinity, but neither one would allow me to get out on port 22. I need port 22 (SSH) to connect to AWS, and any FTP site that requires SFTP.

Thinking Xfinity was blocking port 22 on their hardware, I bought a Netgear CM1000 modem and Netgear R7000 wireless router. Hooked them up this morning, and still can't get out on port 22.

Spent an hour on the phone with Netgear trying to open port 22, but no go. Netgear said there is nothing more they can do and the issue is with Xfinity.

Reverted to my ancient Ubee, and port 22 works again.

Any advice most appreciated!

EDIT WITH ADDED INFO AND UPDATE

Here is more complete info on my current equipment... the stuff that lets me SSH ... and what I've tried that won't let me out.

My old Ubee modem is connected to a Vonage router for VOIP (Motorola VONAGE VT2442-VD). I have hardwired my desktop into the Vonage router, and off of the Vonage device, I run an old TrendNet wireless. With this setup, I can SSH (port 22) from both the desktop (wired) and my laptop (wired and wireless).

When I went from the Ubee to the Xfinity-provided Arris modem/router/wap, I could not SSH. I could not get out on Port 22.

Same thing when I set up the Netgear CM1000 and Netgear R7000... I could not SSH. I could not get out on Port 22.

As Keltari suggested, I tried the new Netgear R7000 with the Ubee modem. Thought for sure I would get out, but no go. I could not SSH. And now I'm really stumped.

Is there something in the Vonage router setup that is letting me get out?

Answer (score 1):

According to Xfinity's [website](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/list-of-blocked-ports), they do not block port 22.  It is strange that you cant SSH easily.  Whats stranger is that its blocking outgoing, typically nothing outgoing is blocked on a router.  Hook one of your new routers after the Ubee and before your PC.  If port 22 is still blocked outgoing from your PC, then its definitely the new router thats preventing you from getting out.  You will have to check its configuration.

Comment: I added more info and update. Thanks for your help.